# Calling API in R (httr package)

Tags: r, json, http-headers, httr

Hope you can help me, I am not an expert on integrations :)

There is a system called social bakers (doc: https://api.socialbakers.com) where I try to fetch some data. I have a token, a secret and I think I am doing the first part right.

I am just trying to connect using this snippet:

```
library(httr)

req <- GET("https://api.socialbakers.com/0/facebook/profiles", 
       authenticate("token", "secret", type = "basic"))
stop_for_status(req)
content(req)
```

This works perfectly. I have a JSON response which I can parse into a table.
My question is about another URL like this:

```
library(httr)

req <- GET("https://api.socialbakers.com/0/facebook/metrics", 
       authenticate("token", "secret", type = "basic"))
stop_for_status(req)
content(req)
```

The same code, doesn't work anymore, returning

> code 405 HTTP Method Invalid

I am not sure if I am doing right, some part of the doc says I have to use base64 on the header, but why is working in the first part? Some advice will be really appreciated :)

EDIT:

SOLVED: In that case, the correct method to interact with the API is using the POST method to send the parameters to the service.

The following snippet was used.

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)

doc <- POST("https://api.socialbakers.com/0/facebook/metrics",
        authenticate("user",
                     "pass",
                     type = "basic"), 
        body = list(
          date_start = "2016-01-11",
          date_end = "2016-01-12",
          profiles = c("12345", "123456"),
          metrics = c("fans_count_lifetime", "fans_change"))
        , encode = "json")
stop_for_status(doc)
content(doc)
```

Comment: Per documentation at the link you provided, requests for metrics requires arguments. They have an [example request](https://api.socialbakers.com/#facebook-metrics) (right side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, the correct method to interact with the API is using the POST method to send the parameters to the service.

The following snippet was used.

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)

doc <- POST("https://api.socialbakers.com/0/facebook/metrics",
    authenticate("user",
                 "pass",
                 type = "basic"), 
    body = list(
      date_start = "2016-01-11",
      date_end = "2016-01-12",
      profiles = c("12345", "123456"),
      metrics = c("fans_count_lifetime", "fans_change"))
    , encode = "json")
stop_for_status(doc)
content(doc)enter code here
```